# How to install FFmpeg developer libraries on Debian 7

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, debian

I have searched the internet and all the answers I find are on how to install the binaries to use the ffmpeg line command. I need to install the include and libs to compile C++ programs using ffmpeg. I had them installed my Debian 7(don't remember how they were first installed), but now I tried to update them to version 3.2 by doing apt-get install libavformat-dev and what happened is that libav (the dissident library from FFmpeg) got install instead, breaking my code. I don't remember compiling FFmpeg from source the first time I did it, and I would prefer not to have to compile it myself. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I know you said that you don't want to compile it, but it isn't hard and may be easier than looking for some random, third-party repository.

An untested, basic example:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config wget
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.2.9.tar.gz
tar xzvf ffmpeg-3.2.9.tar.gz
cd ffmpeg-3.2.9
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Uninstall with:

```
cd ffmpeg-3.2.9
sudo make uninstall
```

For a more details see [FFmpeg Wiki: Debian Compile Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Note that this guide "installs" to `~/ffmpeg_build` and `~/bin`, but you can modify/simplify it to install to the system (`/usr/local/`) if you prefer.

Probably not really worth mentioning, but if you also have the Libav stuff installed make sure your code is using your newly compiled FFmpeg libraries instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install ffmpeg libav-tools libavcodec-dev libavcodec57 libavdevice-dev libavdevice57 libavfilter-dev libavfilter6 libavformat-dev libavformat57 libavresample-dev libavresample3 libavutil-dev libavutil55 libpostproc-dev libpostproc54 libswresample-dev libswresample2 libswscale-dev libswscale4
```

Comment: libavformat-dev/libavutil-dev/libavcodec-dev is what I tried and it installed libav instead of FFmpeg. When I look at the header files I see they are from the libav library, not FFmpeg.